# Different FIPS Codes Versions for Counties

Tags: geoprocessing, database, fips

I am a SQL guy writing queries for supply chain consultants. I know little about FIPS.

I found in our database, at least three versions of FIPS code for counties. The number of FIPS are from 3100 to 3300.

This caused many troubles, if I inner join (merge) on the FIPS code, but the FIPS are not the same across the entire database.

How to manage the different versions of FIPS code?

Should I do something like referencing?

What if county A in 2000 split into county AA and county AAA in 2010?

Can you introduce how do you manage such issue?

---

"at least three versions of FIPS code" means there are at least 3 different total number of FIPS code (for county). The smallest is about 3140, the largest about 3250.

If the number of FIPS is not same for table A and table B, it will cause trouble when you join table A and table B.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  The tour states that there should be only one question per question, however you have asked multiple questions, making this too broad.  Please [edit] your question to narrow it down to one specific question, or ask your questions separately.

Comment: Also can you expand on what you mean by "at least three versions of FIPS code", and outline your process and the troubles you had trying to join.

Comment: @Midavalo Took the tour and edited the question.